# Grouping Node Comment in Views

Tags: views, comments

I am trying to set up the following in Views:

**Review 1**
-Example Field
-All Comments of the Review

**Review 2**
-Example Field
-All Comments of the Review

I'm pulling in the comments from a relationship. However, rather than grouping all the comments under the review, it duplicates the Review:

**Review 1**
-Example Field
-Comment 1

**Review 1**
-Example Field
-Comment 2

And so forth. How can I group all the comments to not duplicate the node, and just appear in order and grouped for the review node?

Comment: Have you set the relationship as "required"?

Comment: that didn't seem to change anything. the comments show up without a problem, they just appear one at a time, and duplicate my review for each comment of that node.

Comment: i've been playing around with field sorting, but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried the format settings for your row style? You can define a field to group the output by...

Comment: that's what i'm experimenting with now. i've tried grouping by comment id, nid, author, etc.

Comment: Try "title" (of the review)...

Comment: That's what I would have thought, but it still splits the review up.

Comment: didn't figure out the problem, but i changed the relationship to just show the last comment from the node.

Answer (score 0):

I know an old post anyway. There two solutions to this, [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3424/nodes-with-comments-in-view) is one, but for this you need to define the type of the view as comment view right from the start, However another solution is that (Assuming Review 1, Review 2 are nodes being pulled and a relationship is set on the `comment and node`), right below the `Title` block you have the `FORMAT` configuration block, set it to `Unformatted list` and to display the `fields` (Notice: I have not tested on other formats such as table etc), click on `Settings` after the `|`pipe symbol and you can see `Grouping field Nr.1`  with a drop down, choose `nid` as your grouping method. In other cases there might be `Grouping field Nr.2/3..` and so on. This should be able to group all your comments together for a node.